# looking for some tools that show the complexity of my methods

Tags: visual-studio, performance

I am looking for some tools and VS plugins that can show me if some of my methods are inefficient etc... mostly looking for complexity of the algorithms in some of them at this point... if you know of some good free tools: Great...if they are commercial it is still Ok if I can use their trial version for a few days...I am using professional editions of VS 2008 and 2010.

Thanks

Comment: Is this just for curiosity, or are you interested in removing inefficiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VisualStudio you can calculate the code metrics for your project/solution. Open your project / solution, click on menu "Analyze" and you will find menuitems like "Calculate code metrics for ...".

Comment: While Professional 2010 doesn't have it by default, you can find an add in in the Extensions Gallery by searching for "Code Metrics"